# Помогите реализовать итерационную функцию на python 3

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import math


def main(m, y, a, n):
  sum1=0
  for i in range(1, m+1):
      e1 = (y ** 4) / 62 
      e2 = (66 * ((92 * i) **3))
      e3 = 39
      sum1 += e1 + e2 + e3
  result = 1
  for c in range(1, m+1):
      f = 0
      for k in range(1, n+1):
          for j in range(1, a+1):
              f += (k - 57) * (46 * y - (c ** 2 / 19) - (j ** 3 / 33))**3
      result *= f
  return sum1 - result
print(main(6, 0.87, 2, 2))
```

Код не работает выдает -5.4121839714515246e+42 вместо -6.35e+42

Comment: Похоже должно быть `f += k - 57 * (....)` при вычислении `ПΣΣ`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в действии `(k-57)`, оно не должно быть в скобках

```
f += k - 57 * ((46 * y - (c ** 2 / 19) - (j ** 3 / 33))**3)
```

Comment: Емае, спасибо большое. И как я не заметил.